# How to install a .ttf font in Xubuntu 11.10 32-bit

Tags: xubuntu, fonts

I installed the OCR-A font in Ubuntu 11.10 64-bit using the Font Viewer. As usual, I just double-clicked the file and then Install, without problems. But, when I tried to do the same in another PC with Xubuntu 11.10 32-bit, it simply does nothing. I installed gnome-font-viewer to try it (I know Xubuntu uses Xfce, but nothing worked). So, do anyone know how to install a font in Xubuntu 32-bit? Will I need another kind of font viewer?

Comment: did you manually copy the font into the .fonts of the home folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to both for your answers. But I tried that and it didn't work. I couldn't install the font. And when I copied the font in the .fonts folder it simple didn't do nothing. I tried different stuff, but nothing worked. I solved this problem from the Software Center, I got into the Fonts section and I typed OCR (the font i was wanting to install) and it appeared only one option. It was what I was looking for. I just installed, then I checked in the Libre Office writer, and the was installed.

Answer (score 8):

After installing `gnome-font-viewer`, opening the font with it and clicking 'Install Font' should do the trick for the current user.

Alternatively, you can just copy the fonts to the `~/.fonts` directory.

If you want to make the font available system-wide, copy the font files to `/usr/share/fonts` and then run `sudo mkfontdir`.